# How to attach virtual (SSH) session to (systemd) seat0?

Tags: udev, pam, multiseat, loginctl

I am logging in on a PC using SSH and need to access some devices which are attached to seat0.
`loginctl` shows that my session is not attached to any seat:

```
SESSION  UID USER      SEAT TTY  
     50 1000 septatrix      pts/0
```

The devices are added to the seat using udev rules though I explicitly do not want to make the device world read-/writeable or add it to another group.
Reading though the man pages for `systemd-logind`, `pam_systemd` etc did not lead me anywhere helpful but only confirmed the fact that virtual session are not assigned any seat be default.
However I was unable to find information how it is determined if a session is "virtual" or whether it can be configured for pam/logind/udev...

Comment: Do you want to treat *every* incoming SSH session as equivalent to a local seat0 session, or do you wish only a *particular* SSH session (or sessions) to have this privilege? If the latter, do you want it for your user account only, for some group of users, or do you wish to determine the set of privileged sessions in some other way?

Comment: I am fine with all SSH sessions being attached to seat0. Having more control is of course appreciated but most importantly do SSH session require access to the devices (without having to use `sudo`/`setfacl` etc.)